# Using DB2, can I check when a stored procedure was modified?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

I see that some versions of MSSQL allow you to run a query to retrieve information about stored procedures.  I also saw the same type of query for Oracle.  Is there anything similar for DB2?

Specifically, I am hoping to be able to see when a stored procedure was created and/or last modified.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This should be what you are looking for:

```
select routinename, create_time, alter_time from syscat.routines where routinetype='P'
```

Comment: This gives me:`[SQL0204] ROUTINES in SYSCAT type *FILE not found.`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can check in DB2 when stored procedure is modified.
Please find below Query for the same. Don't confuse for CREATE_TIME this means last modified time.

Code as below:

SELECT PROCNAME, CREATE_TIME
FROM SYSCAT.procedures WHERE PROCNAME = '<>' order by CREATE_TIME desc

Note: Replace <> with your actual stored procedure name.

Comment: Please, format the code in order to difference it from description/explanation.